# How to get a HttpResponse text

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

I'm uploading a file by using rest, and getting a response from the server, in case and the upload succeed (response code 200) I'm also getting a guid for this operation, the header looks like this :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 36
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 07:00:56 GMT

**772fb809-61d5-4e12-b6f2-133f55ed9ac7** // the guid
```

I was wonder how can I pull out this guid ? should I use getInputStream() ?

10x

Comment: why dont you try to use getInputStream and see what happens

Comment: That seems to be the header and at least some of the body.

Comment: I've tried getInputStream, but how can I pull the data out of it ? 
getinputstream().read() to byte array and then convert to string might help ?

Comment: @lgal you can use a bufferedreader: `InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
  while(br.ready()){
   String line = br.readLine();
   //line has the contents returned by the inputStream
  }`

Comment: Great, worked like a charm :)
please add it as an answer and I'll mark it as a sulution

Comment: @lgal cool... i am glad to have helped, just posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one `BufferedReader`, here is one example:

```
InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream(); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
while(br.ready()){ 
    String line = br.readLine(); 
    //line has the contents returned by the inputStream 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the response you have shared, it seems that you are getting the guid in the body and not in header. Headers are generally name-value pair.

You need to read the response body and get the guid. If you guid is the only thing in the response then you can do somehting like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://yourwebserviceurl");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String guid = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(guid );
```

[IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) is from apache.

Comment: @Igal You need to import the apache jar from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/